# sklearn Perceptron learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand how Perceptron from sklearn.linear_model performs fit() function ([Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html#sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.fit)). Question comes from this piece of code:

```
clf = Perceptron()
clf.fit(train_data, train_answers)

print('accuracy:', clf.score(train_data, train_answers))
accuracy: 0.7
```

I thought goal of fitting is to create classification function which will give answer with 100% accuracy on test data, but in the example above it gives only 70%. I have tried one more data set where accuracy was 60%.

What do I misunderstand in fitting process?

Comment: Please provide details regarding the case you are working with (input and output, quality of data etc.). Unless you provide that it is practically impossible to receive a useful answer.

Comment: Please grab a book on machine-learning and read about prediction-error, model-capabilities, generalization-error and co... It seems, you are missing *all* the basics. Sry.

Comment: First note, the docs say "linear model". In general, training a machine learning algorithm will not give you 100% accuracy on your training data. This is particularly true for a linear model. Consider a diagram of two classes of objects spread across two dimensions. If the class points highly overlap, then a classifier would have to be very high variance to create a (non-linear) boundary separating 100% of the training data. Usually, this represents tremendous overfitting, and is undesirable.

Comment: @sascha I'm trying to complete Coursera Intro to ML, but there's only general things about algorithms. So I have questions like this. Please advice me some good book if you can.

Comment: @rpd, thanks for comment. For instance, I took two arrays:
train_data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
train_answers = np.array([0, 1, 0])

Comment: @JohnYetter thanks for explanation. Can you advice me a place to start learning?

Comment: The Coursera class is excellent, but it does not cover libraries (other than for SVM). You will learn more about Neural Nets, if you roll your own, following the class notes, but there are several Neural Net implementations like PyBrain2.

Comment: @GlebAbroskin - I would personally recommend you to start with [this](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) book. This introduces Machine Learning with little mathematics. It is a prerequisite to the famous book: "Elements of Statistical Learning" by the same authors.

Comment: @AbhinavArora thanks!

Comment: @JohnYetter we are probably speaking about different courses, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your training data pattern distribution. In the graph shown below, could you find a **straight line** to separate blue and red? Obviously not, and this is the point. Your data must be linearly separable for
[Perceptron Learning Algorithm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~htlin/mooc/doc/02_handout.pdf) to achieve 100% accuracy on training data. Otherwise, no straight line can separate it perfectly.

[image]